# R: remove single characters from string

Tags: r, regex

I have a huge string in R where I want to remove single characters from. So for example, the string might be

`blabla a test this that b á`

And the result should be

`blabla test this that`

How do I do this in R?

Comment: please accept an answer if it worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

This splits the string and filters the substrings by length, no regex:

```
string <- "blabla a test this that b á"
paste(Filter(function(x) nchar(x) > 1,
             unlist(strsplit(string, " "))), 
      collapse=" ")
# [1] "blabla test this that"
```

(does not work with multiple space characters)

Comment: You might get it to work with multiple space characters by using strsplit(string, "\\W+", perl=TRUE). That should enable perl regex matching and then split based on one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: If you want to split on multiple spaces, you can also just use `'\\s+'` as split.